# I can not uninstall skype from the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: uninstall, skype

I tried opening ubuntu software center to uninstall skype, but it doesn't list ANY software under the installed tab.  it doesn't list my firefox browser, skype, or anything else.  What do I do now?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Hello Eva; Welcome to the community!  Would you care to look at this picture here : http://i.imgur.com/NFZw7ph.jpg  and confirm that you have tried this? Also; do you know what version of Ubuntu you are running?